# Azure Devops, how to add "Work Item type" in devops backlog

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I have created a new work item type "Risk" and would like to add to the backlog shortcut as shown in the image below. My version of Azure DevOps is hosted by Microsoft. Pls advise :)

[image]

Comment: Once you added a new work item type, have you applied the customized process to your project? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-wit?view=azure-devops#apply-the-customized-process-to-your-project

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I did and I can see my new Work Item Type from "Left Panel > Work Items". Actually I am referring to the "Backlogs > User Story", at the extreme left there is a plus icon which currently you can create Task and Bug. I want to add my Risk over there.

Comment: I found it! Under Organisation Setting > 'Your custom process' > Backlog Levels > Under Iteration backlog, you can add more work items over there.

Comment: It would be great if you shape your solution as the answer below and accept it so that others arriving in this thread could see that immediately.

Answer (score 4):

I found it! Under Organisation Setting > 'Your custom process' > Backlog Levels > Under Iteration backlog, you can add more work items over there